# Google Sheet: How to search & extract specific value from a long and multiple line of texts in single cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Hello and good day everyone!

I need your help and advise, i've one set of table and data as per below, and i'd like to use a formula to extract specific value from a single cell by using some value as indicator to indicate which text's line to extract.

Given the sample table as below,

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| This is example of the long texts value with multiple line this text is very long also included value as below, Company: Apple Inc Contractor name: John Wick the value above, is per line.. and this text continue.. continue text.. example text again.. | This is where i'd like to display the **Company name** extracted from **Column A** | This is where i'd like to display **Contractor name** extracted from **Column A** |

Example of what i want to achieve,

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| This is example of the long texts value with multiple line this text is very long also included value as below, Company: Apple Inc Contractor name: John Wick the value above, is per line.. and this text continue.. continue text.. example text again.. | Apple Inc | John Wick |

I've tried with
`LEFT()`
`MID()`
`=LEFT(A2,SEARCH("Company",A2)-1)`
`=REGEXREPLACE(A2,"(.*)Company(.*)","$2")`
with no success.

May I request your advise and help on this please!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, how about the following sample formula?

#### Sample formula:

Retrieve "Company name".

```
=TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"Company:(.+)"))
```

Retrieve Contractor name

```
=TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"Contractor name:(.+)"))
```

#### Testing:

When these formulas are used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- For example, the base data is put to the cells "A1:A3", you can also use the following formulas.

  ```
    =ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A3,"Company:(.+)")))

    =ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A3,"Contractor name:(.+)")))
  ```

#### Reference:

- [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)